Can we add custom keybinding on VSCODE's VIm Extension?
I was using Vim in visual studio code, i want to use 'jj' to exit from insert mode. How can add this custom keybinding in visual studio code.
I tried to add it in VS CODE shortcuts. but i can't see any option to add our own shortcuts.

This is shown on the examples in VsCodeVim home page in github here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#quick-example and here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim?tab=readme-ov-file#key-remapping  You could also try using a vimrc file instead, just as you would for regular vim and see if it works, as noted as well: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim?tab=readme-ov-file#vimrc-support.

You can modify your user settings to add this custom. Adding the following code to your settings.json will help you use jj to exit insert mode.
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": [
                "j",
                "j"
            ],
            "after": [
                "<Esc>"
            ]
        }
    ]

If you want to learn more about how to customize your vim in vscode, official docs may help you a lot VSCodeVim
